# How to hide .pyc files when you enter `ls` in bash

Tags: python, linux, ls, pyc

When I perform `ls` in bash, I always see too many `*.pyc` files. Is there any way to hide these files?

Comment: Was there a significant reason behind this? I was annoyed/distracted by them myself (for a purpose of a talk with live demo); that's why I've ended up here. It _sounds_ like you were also only _annoyed_.

Answer (score 33):

This way lies the dark side, but you could force `ls` to never show them by adding something like

```
alias ls='ls --hide="*.pyc"'
```

to your `.bashrc`. `ls` will reveal the hidden files if you use `-a` or `-A`.

However, I would recommend just ignoring them in your head, or running this version of `ls` when you *really* don't want to see them.

Comment: alias ls=`ls --ignore="*.pyc"` did not work for me. but `alias ls="ls --ignore="*.pyc""` did work

Comment: `alias ls='ls --hide=*.pyc'` might be better as this is overridden when you use `-a` option or search using wildcards like `ls *.pyc`

Comment: That's a really good point, thanks.  I didn't know about that option.

Comment: I went ahead and removed `--ignore` from the answer. `--hide` is definitely preferable.

Comment: It is probably a better idea to alias to something a little different.. like `alias lsl='ls --hide="*.pyc"'` so you don't nerf `ls` but have the functionality you want available easily.

Comment: To retain default colouring, use this: alias ls='ls --color=auto --hide=*.pyc'

Comment: @TheoBelaire I've found the solution for OSX. (1) `brew install coreutils` (2) Put `alias lsp='gls --hide="*.pyc"'` to your `~/.bash_profile`; Then you can use `lsp` to `ls` without seeing `*.pyc`. (`lsp` is a command name I created which stands for "ls for python")